Binded file does not update inside Docker container
I run my Docker container with docker-compose and create a bind mount with directory with contains single file. This file is being modified on host machine but the changes are not present inside the container.
Service configuration from docker-compose.yaml:
filebeat:
    image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:${STACK_VERSION}
    user: root
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /Users/avolkov/logs/app
        target: /usr/share/filebeat/logs
      - /Users/avolkov/elastic/filebeat.docker.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/docker/containers/:/var/lib/docker/containers/:ro
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=${HOST_ADDRESS}:9200
      - KIBANA_HOST=${HOST_ADDRESS}:5601
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
    command: ["--strict.perms=false"]
    deploy:
      mode: global

The problem appears with app.log file which is stored in /Users/avolkov/logs/app directory. It's the logging file updating with my Java application and log4j2. I discovered that this file does not update while my application is running. How can I avoid this problem? Seems like that the file should be edited with save event which is performs only when my application stops.
I expected that external changes of this file will be available inside container.

It won't change in real time, you need to restart the container if you want to see the changes that you made on your computer. https://medium.com/@jonsbun/why-need-to-be-careful-when-mounting-single-files-into-a-docker-container-4f929340834

For now I found out that the problem only concerns the logging file, which is not updated in the container while the application is running. Right after the application stops, the file updates inside container. So, I'll edit the question
